# Deserialize json file with dynamic fields into class with java

Tags: java, json

We have a JSON file providing us with data that needs to be loaded in memory, however I'm having a lot of trouble parsing the file as it does not use mapping of fields like I have seen classically:

```
{
  "1er":{
    "baccalaureat": [
      {
        "prog": "genie logiciel",
        "limite": 30
      },
      {
        "prog": "genie civil",
        "limite": 15
      },
      {
        "prog": "genie electrique",
        "limite": 25
      },
      {
        "prog": "Medecine",
        "limite": 34
      },
      {
        "prog": "actuariat",
        "limite": 25
      }
    ]
  },
  "2e":{
    "maitrise": [
      {
        "prog": "informatique",
        "limite": 25
      }
    ]
  },
  "3e":{
    "doctorat": [
      {
        "prog": "informatique",
        "limite": 21
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I use to deal with JSON files with "property" : "value" and I was hoping to be able to use jackson annotations. I've tried a test class shaped like this:

```
public class ClassOne {
    @JsonProperty
    public String Level;

    @JsonProperty
    public String[] programs;
}
```

But alas it does not working, throwing a mismatchedInputException. Of course, but I don't know how to map the properties, then:

```
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    private ProgramLimitService programLimitService;

    public ProgramLimitsLoader() {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

    private static List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();

    public void load(String path) {
        File file = new File(path);

        ClassOne[] classes;

        try {
            classes = objectMapper.readValue(file, ClassOne[].class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new FileCantBeOpenException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I feel like it's because the structure of my class while I'm deserializing is wrong, but I can't put the finger on the problem.

Comment: `ClassOne` has no member variables to that of your json file. Probably why you are getting `mismatchedInputException`

Comment: Yeah well the value "1er" does not have a field mapped. I was hoping that the value would be blindly put in a string, but it seems like jackson annotations does not like that.

Comment: No, Jaskon annotations doesn't work like that. It is looking for a keyword `level` and keyword `programs`

Comment: Exact. You are right. So, if I understand correctly, I cannot user jackson annotations here. How can I proceed then?

Comment: In Groovy there is a ```JsonSlurper``` class which can parse any JSON document without having properly structured classes available. I copied this idea into a Java class which parses any JSON document with Jackson into a simple flat ```HashMap```. Please take a look at the documentation of that class: http://stefanfrings.de/bfUtilities/javadoc/de/stefanfrings/parsing/JsonSlurper.html. The source code (http://stefanfrings.de/bfUtilities/bfUtilities.zip) might be helpful for you.